# Do refunded Google Play purchases show up on credit card bill?

Tags: google-play-store

When you purchase an app that costs money on Google Play but then refund it within the 15 minute leniency period, does any record of the purchase and subsequent refund show up on the bill from the credit card you used to make the purchase? If so, what would show up on the bill?

Comment: Not on mine anyway. I assume the payment is held until the fifteen minutes has passed.

Comment: @RossC Thanks. Can you post this as an answer, and then I'll accept it so we both get reputation? Thanks.

Comment: Done and expanded on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't get any refund on my credit card statement. Nor do I get a debit to begin with for the initial purchase.

The payment is probably held for the fifteen minute refund window. Chances are the actual payment run from Google to the financial institution is done in a batch or a few batches throughout the day. The specifics of the transaction run is down to Google and their bank(s).  I'd imagine they send the debit leg of it after the fifteen minutes from your account and credit an internal suspense account and then send out the batch during the day as I said.

That's only a rough guess but I have worked in software testing similar payments in financial institutions for a long time. It may vary in different countries, I'm in Ireland but I would like to see how it works in other regions.

If, hypothetically you did see a refund for any purchase like this you would see a debit for the purchase and a corresponding credit to your account for the refund with some reference to the app, music or whatever you have purchased.